# Instagram api integration

Tags: instagram

When I am trying to integrate instagram api, It is asking for access token and also I need the client ID.

When I tried to register the new client it is showing 'Registration Disabled' button instead of 'Register a new client' button.

https://prnt.sc/swbiy4

Comment: Did you check my answer? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Instagram has changed the way of showing feeds.

Now to show Instagram feeds, we need to get the **User Token** from **Facebook**.

To obtain it from your Facebook account, please follow the process mentioned below:

- Go to https://developers.facebook.com/ and click on the login link in the top right section.
- Login with your Facebook credentials.
- Click on the My Apps link [REF: my-apps.png] and then click on the Create App link [REF: My-Apps.png].

[image: Create-app]

- Fill in the Display Name of the App (for example Feeds App) by which you can identify your app and the Contact Email address (where Facebook will contact in case of any terms violation, policy changes, or usage restrictions), then click on the Create App ID button. [REF: app-details.png]

[image: app-details]
 - Check the "I'm not a robot" checkbox and click on the Submit button.
Now click on Settings > Basic > Add Platform [REF: add-platform.png], then click on the Website option and enter the information to the Site URL field, and finally click on the Save Changes button.
 - Click on Products link and then choose Set Up for the Instagram option.
 - Now, under the Products link, some new links will start display. Click on the Basic Display link. [REF: basic-display.png]

[image: Basic-display]
 - Click on the Create New App button. [REF: create-new-app.png]

[image: Create-new-app]
 - Provide the display name and click on the Create App button.
 - Provide the website's URL in the Client OAuth settings, Deauthorize, and Data Deletion Requests fields and then click on the Save changes button. [REF: authorization-info.png]

[image: authorization-info]

- Navigate to Roles > Roles. [REF: add-instagram-testers.png]

[image: add-instagram-testers]

- Click on Add Instagram Testers button. [REF: add-instagram-testers.png]
- Enter your Instagram username and click on the Submit button.
- Now, open https://www.instagram.com/ and login with the same user which you entered in the last step.
- Click on the profile icon on the top right corner and then click on the cogwheel icon. [REF: cogwheel-icon.png]

[image: cogwheel-icon]

- Click on the Apps and Websites link, and then click on the TESTER INVITES tab and click on the Accept button.
- Go back to App, choose Instagram > Basic Display. In the User Token Generator field, click on Generate Token [REF: generate-token.png]

[image: generate-token]

- In the pop-up window, provide the Instagram login credentials and click on the Login button.
- Click on Authorize [REF: Authorize.png].

[image: Authorize]

- The Instagram Access Token will be displayed. Check the checkbox "I Understand", Copy the token, and then click on the done button.

That's it.

Comment: I am implementing it, if it works for me, I will accept it as answer.

Comment: @Yogita, did the above process not work for you? It is tried and tested for three projects.

Comment: Your solution worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @AmritPalSingh, great to know that I could help.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora does it work on localhost(127.0.0.1)? Also can you please mention what would be the redirect URI?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I would really appreciate your suggestions on this **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984334/instagram-basic-display-api-error-invalid-scope-basic-or-invalid-redirect**

Answer (score 0):

Instagram API has changed. Now you need to create facebook account and then you will be able to generate access token. this video should help [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWUcb8jXgVA). Or you can search something like "Instagram graph api 2020".
**edit:**
You need to know, that the first generated token is available for 1 hour. Next for 30 days, and you have to recreate it every 30 days.